# Couldn't be able to insert data into MySQL even if I enter write query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am having trouble inserting data in the mySQL through php,

First of all i created the Database and its table using PHpmyadmin,

my table is as follows,

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    firstsname varchar(12) NOT NULL,
        lastname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        gender varchar(6) NOT NULL,
        dob varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        address varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        town varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        states varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        postcode int(4) NOT NULL,
        emailaddress varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
        phonenumber int(10) NOT NULL,
        comments varchar(1000) NULL       
);
```

After I created the table i connect to the database where this table is located called `testing`, using this code,

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pwd = "";
$sql_db = "testing";
$conn = @mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pwd,$sql_db);

if (!$conn) {
    echo "<p>Connection has failed!</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>Success</p>";
}
```

I get `Success` message on the screen that means the connection is successful, but when I try to write in to this table using PHP i always get error, but when I run the same query in phpmyadmin then it works and add the table row into database,

This is what I am doing in PHP,

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users ('firstname', 'lastname', 'gender', 'dob', 'address', 'town', 'states', 'postcode', 'emailaddress', 'phonenumber', 'comments') 
VALUES ('asds', 'adssad', 'male', '04/08/1991', 'saddadsasd', 'dasasd', 'adssad', '1111', 'dasdas@dassda.com', '1111111111', 'adssaddsadsa')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if (!$result){
    echo "ERROR";
} else {
    echo "Done";
}
mysqli_close ($conn);
```

and I always get ERROR when I run it.

Why it works through phpmyadmin but not with PHP ?

Comment: Instead of echoing mere string saying "error" or "done", try using built-in functions to get potential errors...

Comment: Turn on PHP's error reporting and it'll tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Column names has to have backticks ` (or nothing), not single quotes.

Comment: Do this `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));` and you'll see the errors you're making.

Comment: @RileyWillow , single quotes should only be Outside Column Value , not Column name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users ('firstname', 'lastname', 'gender', 'dob', 'address', 'town', 'states', 'postcode', 'emailaddress', 'phonenumber', 'comments') 
VALUES ('asds', 'adssad', 'male', '04/08/1991', 'saddadsasd', 'dasasd', 'adssad', '1111', 'dasdas@dassda.com', '1111111111', 'adssaddsadsa')";
```

To

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, gender, dob, address, town, states, postcode, emailaddress, phonenumber, comments) 
VALUES ('asds', 'adssad', 'male', '04/08/1991', 'saddadsasd', 'dasasd', 'adssad', '1111', 'dasdas@dassda.com', '1111111111', 'adssaddsadsa')";
```

Notice I have changed the column names to not have the quotes.

If you really wanted you could potentially use ticks:

```
INSERT INTO users (`firstname`, `lastname`
```

However, I would suggest no quotes and no ticks.

Comment: I tried that already it didn't work either.

Comment: actually i also tried inserting directly from phpmyadmin and then using the generated query with ticks in php, but it didn't work either.

Comment: @RileyWillow when you execute the PHP code above, is anything actually inserted into the DB? As I believe I have had issues with `UPDATES` as technically nothing was returned, but the query was successful. So would be an idea to check this.

Comment: *"However, I would suggest no quotes and no ticks."* - One would use ticks, if and when the OP happens to unknowingly, use a reserved word, or it contains a space, a hyphen or anything else that will give MySQL something to complain about ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- very true, for the OP's info here are the reserved words, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html. It's suprising how many times you can actually conflict with a reserved word.